# Combined test coverage report with jMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, code-coverage, jmockit

I am using jmockit with Ant. For each test file run, an `index.html` file gets created/over-written in the coverage report folder.

For multiple test files, this `index.html` gets over-written.

I am looking for a combined report for all files. what should be done? I have read about using `.ser` files but I do not know how to create and then use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a [look here](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html#merging). The trick is to set

```
-Djmockit-coverage-output=merge
```

(or `serial` - read up on the differences in the link above).

Cheers,

Comment: what would be two directories since .ser is missing and there is a single index.html? Though I have html file for each class in same directory structure as source.

Comment: whatever im trying is giving "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from coverage.jar"

Comment: have added <jvmarg  value = "-Djmockit-coverage-output=serial"/> but then some exceptns hv started coming and index file is still same.